# windows service can't access desktop UI

Tags: windows, windows-services, user32, worker-service, .net-services

recently I made a service that get the current active window of the user for windows which uses [GetForegroundWindow in user32.dll](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getforegroundwindow) and it's perfectly working while running as a console application, but when I convert it to a service and install it in windows services, it can't get the window : `Unable to enumerate the process modules`
How I can fix this?